# Is there a way to "unroll" URL Shorteners?

Tags: web, usability, url-shortener

URL Shorteners are useful in space-constrained media like Twitter. But the dangers of such have been well-discussed (limited lifespan, hiding malicious links, usability, etc). But is there a nice way to pre-resolve shortened URLs from services like goo.gl or bit.ly? I'd like to do it at the time when the user enters them on my site/community.

Comment: Using what technology / language / platform? Client side or server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LongURL](http://longurl.org/) has [an API](http://longurl.org/api) available for doing exactly this, and supports more than 300 different URL shorteners.

Answer (score 0):

Well .. the one way that works with all url shorteners would be to create a script on your site that calls the shortened url to get the adress where it redirects to .. that should work with all shorteners without using their api.

Answer (score 0):

Just open it using ex. cURL and check headers to detect redirection.